# CSV Import Tables

Tags: import

Hi I would like to import tables through CSV, any particular plugins or functions that can help me do that? I would like to have them stand in their own table and then the user would be able to include them via shortcode and id e.g. [table id=1] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are a few but the one that stands out is [**WP-Table Reloaded**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/) plugin which answers your requirements and has endless of customization options and features.

Comment: WP-Table-Reloaded is no longer available